# CA Arcserver 16.1 SP1 - Magazine is ejected after every job

Tags: library, backup

I have verified under the backup job > Options > Operation that "Do Not Eject" is selected, and I have verified that under Device Setup > Library Properties > Eject Media is Not selected.  What else to check?

Comment: Did you restart the services after you did that? IIRC, with CA in order for the changes to take a effect - the services had to be restarted.

Comment: @Cole  - yes I restarted the tape engine

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I have jobs set to mount and dismount the magazine and the dismount command is either flaky or has changed in this newer version - But it was the culprit.